Finding a projective change of coordinates
Let $F$ be an homogenous polynomial of degree d in $ \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$, $F \in C^{\infty}$.
Let $\mathcal{C}=\{ [X_0,Y_0,Z_0] \in \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C}) \mid F[X_0,Y_0,Z_0]=0\}$.
Let $o$ be a point in $\mathbb{P}^2$, $s$ a line. $o \notin s, o \notin \mathcal{C}, s \not \subseteq \mathcal{C}$.
Let's consider $ \pi: \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})-\{o\} \rightarrow s$, defined by $ a \rightarrow r \cap s$, where r is "the line passing through o and a".
Since $o \notin \mathcal{C}$, we can consider the restriction $\pi_{\mathcal{C}}:\mathcal{C} \rightarrow s = \mathbb{P}^1$.
Let o be a a particular point so that it doesn't belong to any line intersecting $\mathcal{C}$ in an inflection point, or a bi-tangent line.
Prove that through a change of variables we can assume $ o = [0, 0, 1]$, $s:=\{Z_2 = 0\}$
and the line $\{Z_0=0\}$ intersecting $\mathcal{C}$ in exactly d points.
I tried to be as concise as possible, this is part of a step-by-step guided proof.
I thought maybe a projective change of coordinates might be a solution, but the problem is posed in such a generic case that I couldn't go on.
Any help?

Yes, a projective change of coordinates works. It suffices to use affine coordinates and affine transformations. You should first verify that given any point $o$ and line $s$, there exist affine coordinates $(x,y)$ such that $o$ is the point at infinity and $s$ is the $x$-axis.
